# Integrate React-Semantic-UI and redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, semantic-ui, redux-form

I'm using **redux-form** (awesome libs) to handle my form & **redux** store in **React** app.
Everything works well, important forms and nested json output.

I'm trying to use **React-Semantic-UI** Component with **redux-form**.
I searched inside the docs how about integrate custom component with redux form, and here we go :
http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/faq/CustomComponent.md/
Seems perfect.

But when i integrate Semantic and this, it doenst work.

This is my simple test with pseudo code  :

```
const TestComponent = props => (
<Form>
     <Field name="dropdownTest" component={ TestSelect } />
</Form>
)
```

and here my CustomComponent using Dropdown. You can found the dropdown documentation & props (onChange & value ) here :

http://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown

```
import Form , Dropdown from 'semantic-ui-react'
import {myOption from './myOption'

const TestSelect = field = (
   <Form.Field>
            <label> Test dropdown </label>
             <Dropdown option={myOption} selection 
                                   value={{val : field.input.value}}
                                   onChange={ param => field.input.onChange(param.val)} />
     </Form.Field>
)
```

As in the documentation, I added value & onChange props on my Custom Component.

I clearly miss something here. Is someone have simple example with redux-form and semantc ui ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Ok I succed :

To use React Semantic Dropdown, this is a simple example :

```
const TestComponent = props => (
<Form>
     <Field name="dropdownName" component={ DropdownFormField}
            label="Dropdown Test" 
      />

</Form>
)



const DropdownFormField = props => (
 <Form.Field>
   <Dropdown selection {...props.input}
             value={props.input.value}
             onChange={(param,data) => props.input.onChange(data.value)}
             placeholder={props.label} 
    />
  </Form.Field>
)
```

And everything is working great. 
You can do same with Semantic  and any components.

Hope that somebody found this usefull.

Comment: about a year later...did this approach end up working for you well @GreGGus? I am trying to validate my semantic ui react forms and am having a hard time finding a library to do it

Comment: Yes everything is working. I'm not working on React/ Redux anymore, but this was working well.
Do not forget to handle props.input.value which is the value on Redux & ReduxForm.

Comment: Thanks, two years later this worked for me with radio buttons

Comment: But when i introduce  <Form.Group> </Form.Group> in my Form, it breaks

Answer (score 0):

I found the accepted answer wasn't working in my case, redux form kept firing a `FOCUS` action which kept triggering a re-render and my dropdown field would not open. Possibly my bad, or an update, but didn't have time to debug so came up with this solution.

I'm using Typescript, and wrapped the Semantic UI Dropdown field in a custom component that adds and retrieves the dropdown value from redux form directly.

Works well thus far, should be easy to port to vanilla JS.

**ReduxFormSemanticDropdownComponent**

If using Typescript change `AppState` to be your own state object type.

```
import { DropdownProps, Dropdown, Form, DropdownItemProps } from "semantic-ui-react";
import * as React from "react";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import { AppState } from "../../..";
import { change, formValueSelector } from "redux-form";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

interface OwnProps {
    name: string;
    form: string;
    label: string;
    placeholder?: string;
    options: Array<DropdownItemProps>;
}

interface DispatchProps {
    change: (form: string, field: string, value: string) => void;
}

interface StateProps {
    selectedValue: any;
}

type Props = OwnProps & DispatchProps & StateProps;

class ReduxFormSemanticDropdownComponent extends React.Component<Props> {

    onChange = (value: string) => {
        this.props.change(this.props.form, this.props.name, value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Form.Field>
                <label>{this.props.label}</label>
                <Dropdown
                    placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                    fluid
                    selection
                    value={this.props.selectedValue}
                    onChange={(event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>, data: DropdownProps) => this.onChange(data.value as string)}
                    options={this.props.options}
                />
            </Form.Field>
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<AppState>): DispatchProps => {
    return {
        change: (form: string, field: string, value: string) => dispatch(change(form, field, value)),
    };
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState, ownProps: OwnProps): StateProps => {
    var selector = formValueSelector(ownProps.form);

    return {
        selectedValue: selector(state, ownProps.name)
    }
}

export const ReduxFormSemanticDropdown = connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, OwnProps>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ReduxFormSemanticDropdownComponent);
```

**To Use**

Add this to your normal redux form, and it should behave as a standard field would.

```
<ReduxFormSemanticDropdown
    name="gigType"
    form="applicationForm"
    label="Gig Type"
    options={[
        {
            text: `I'm flexible!`,
            value: 'Flexible',
        },
        {
            text: 'Mid Week (Evening)',
            value: 'MidWeekEvening',
        },
        {
            text: 'Weekend (Afternoon)',
            value: 'WeekendAfternoon',
        },
        {
            text: 'Weekend (Evening)',
            value: 'WeekendEvening',
        }
    ]}
/>
```